# Export root and sub directories to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was wondering does anyone know of a way to export a folder structure from the file system into a SQL Server database table? I can successfully create the structure in a treeview and thought about exporting the structure into the database but can't figure out the best way to do that so that it is represented in the database table correctly. Basically what I am trying to do is create a recursive table structure with a parent/child relationship. For example - `ID, Name, Parentid,` etc.

If anyone has an idea or any idea - thanks in advanced.

**Edit**:

I can display the folder structure on the UI with a treeview with no problem which is not the issue.  The issue is taking that tree structure and exporting it into the database (parent/child representation as stated above).  For example I can represent the tree structure FROM the database with no problem or even from the file system, its basically doing it from the file system and exporting/importing that structure into the database.  Getting it out is not the problem.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem. Some sample data ? what have you tried so far ??

Comment: You could look into [trees](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334) in sql, or a simple parent child relationship.

Comment: [This slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/ehildebrandt/trees-and-hierarchies-in-sql) gives many different ways to handle hierarchies.

Comment: paqogomez - the table structure is not the issue, the issue is getting the structure into the table from code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple tree walk. Given a table like this:

```
create table dbo.directory
(
  id        int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  parent_id int     null               foreign key references dbo.directory( id ) ,
  name      varchar(256) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS not null , -- case-insensensitive, accent-sensitive

  unique ( id , name ) ,

)
go
```

A class like this ought to do you

```
class DirectoryTreeLoader : IDisposable
{
  const string          connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ;
  private SqlConnection Connection       ;
  private SqlCommand    Command          ;
  private bool          CommandPrepared  ;

  private SqlParameter ParentDirectoryId ;
  private SqlParameter DirectoryName     ;

  public DirectoryTreeLoader()
  {
    Connection          = new SqlConnection(connectionString) ;
    Command             = Connection.CreateCommand() ;
    ParentDirectoryId   = new SqlParameter( "@parent_id" , SqlDbType.Int     ,   4 ) ;
    DirectoryName       = new SqlParameter( "@name"      , SqlDbType.VarChar , 256 ) ;

    ParentDirectoryId.IsNullable = true  ;

    DirectoryName.IsNullable     = false ;

    Command.Parameters.Add( ParentDirectoryId ) ;
    Command.Parameters.Add( DirectoryName     ) ;
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;
    Command.CommandText = @"
      insert dbo.directory ( parent_id , name ) values ( @parent_id , @name ) ;
      select id = scope_identity() ;
      ".Trim() ;

    return ;
  }

  public void Load( DirectoryInfo root )
  {
    if ( Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed )
    {
      Connection.Open() ;
      Command.Prepare() ;
    }

    Visit( null , root ) ;

    return ;
  }

  private void Visit( int? parentId , DirectoryInfo dir )
  {
    // insert the current directory
    ParentDirectoryId.SqlValue = parentId.HasValue ? new SqlInt32( parentId.Value ) : SqlInt32.Null ;
    DirectoryName.SqlValue     = new SqlString( dir.Name ) ;

    object o  = Command.ExecuteScalar() ;
    int    id = (int)(decimal) o ;

    // visit each subdirectory in turn
    foreach ( DirectoryInfo subdir in dir.EnumerateDirectories() )
    {
      Visit(id,subdir) ;
    }

    return ;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if ( Command != null )
    {
      Command.Cancel();
      Command.Dispose();
      Command = null ;
    }
    if ( Connection != null )
    {
      Connection.Dispose() ;
      Connection = null ;
    }
    return ;
  }
}
```

Usage?

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo( @"c:\inetpub" ) ;
  using ( DirectoryTreeLoader loader = new DirectoryTreeLoader() )
  {
    loader.Load(root) ;
  }

  return ;
}
```

If you want to eliminate the recursive `Visit()`, just use a stack:

```
public void Load( DirectoryInfo root )
{
  if ( Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed )
  {
    Connection.Open() ;
    Command.Prepare() ;
  }

  Stack<Tuple<int?,DirectoryInfo>> pending = new Stack<Tuple<int?, DirectoryInfo>>();
  pending.Push(new Tuple<int,DirectoryInfo>(null,root) ) ;
  while ( pending.Count > 0 )
  {
    Tuple<int?,DirectoryInfo> dir = pending.Pop() ;

    // insert the current directory
    ParentDirectoryId.SqlValue = dir.Item1.HasValue ? new SqlInt32( dir.Item1.Value ) : SqlInt32.Null ;
    DirectoryName.SqlValue     = new SqlString( dir.Item2.Name ) ;
    object o  = Command.ExecuteScalar() ;
    int parentId = (int)(decimal) o ;

    // push each subdirectory onto the stack
    foreach ( DirectoryInfo subdir in dir.Item2.EnumerateDirectories() )
    {
      pending.Push( new Tuple<int?, DirectoryInfo>(parentId,subdir));
    }

  }

  return ;
}
```

Comment: Life saver. Thank you so much @Nicholas Carey.

Answer (score 0):

You just did it. What is the problem with that structure? You might want to add an attribute column where you can specify if the object is a file or a directory but if you just want to document the directory structure then every object (row) is a directory and you don't need the attribute column.

You can nest that indefinitely.

Now the issue is for you to write the client code to take your nested structure and display it in your UI or what ever else you want to do with it.

To populate your structure .net provides you with the [file system classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getdirectories%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you need to walk the file system that you want to replicate, you just need to insert a row in the db for every directory that you encounter as you recursively traverse the targeted file system.

More specifically, create a recursive function named "walk: that takes two parameters. The first is the name of the directory and the second is the row id of the parent directory. In the walk function, first insert a row in the table with the directory name and parent id that were passed in as parameters. Get the row id of the row just inserted; then call filesystem.getdirectories function and pass it the name of the directory. For each directory returned by that function, call your function back (a recursive call) passing the name of the sub directory and the id of the parent directory. In your main, call the function passing it the name of the root of your tree as the first parameter and a zero as the second parameter, meaning there is no parent at the root level and it will populate the database with your tree structure.

Comment: I can display the folder structure on the UI with a treeview with no problem which is not the issue.  The issue is taking that tree structure and exporting it into the database (parent/child representation as stated above).  For example I can represent the tree structure FROM the database with no problem or even from the file system, its basically doing it from the file system and exporting/importing that structure into the database.  Getting it out is not the problem.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Of course, that was what the last paragraph of my answer was all about. In .net the FileSystem.GetDirectories method returns a collection of strings representing the path names of subdirectories within a directory. Do you know how to recursively call methods? Create a recursive function, and pass it the name of the root of your tree, then for each directory returned, call your function back  passing the name of the sub directory.